# pdf_tex files and \import: PDF file not found

Tags: include, import

I am currently working on my PhD thesis, and I am having trouble including a `pdf_tex` and `pdf` file created using `Inkscape`. I am using `TeXStudio` and `PDFLaTeX`.

The relevant files are:

```
phd_thesis_all/phd_thesis/tex/thesis.tex
phd_thesis_all/phd_thesis/tex/Chapter05/teleoperation.tex
phd_thesis_all/phd_thesis_figs/images/teleoperation/solidworks_model_view.pdf_tex
phd_thesis_all/phd_thesis_figs/images/teleoperation/solidworks_model_view.pdf
phd_thesis_all/phd_thesis_figs/images/teleoperation/solidworks_model_view.png
phd_thesis_all/phd_thesis_figs/images/teleoperation/solidworks_model_view.svg
```

The `svg` has added annotations to the `png` file. This is exported as a `pdf` and `pdf_tex` file for use in the thesis.

The command to include the file with the diagram is in `thesis.tex`.

```
    % Chapter 5
    \FloatBarrier
    \chapter{Teleoperation}
    \label{ch:teleoperation}
    \include{Chapter05/teleoperation}
```

The figure import command in `Chapter05/teleoperation.tex` is:

```
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \import{../../phd_thesis_figs/}{images/teleoperation/solidworks_model_view.pdf_tex}
    \caption{\SolidWorks Model with Coordinate Systems Highlighted}
    \label{fig:solidworks_model_view}
    \end{figure}
```

When I try to compile the document, it comes up with the error:

```
(../../phd_thesis_figs/images/teleoperation/solidworks_model_view.pdf_tex

LaTeX Warning: File `solidworks_model_view.pdf' not found on input line 52.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `solidworks_model_view.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.52 ...length,page=1]{solidworks_model_view.pdf}}
                                                  %
?
```

In other words, it is finding the `.pdf_tex` file just fine, but is choking on the `\includegraphics` command inside to get the `pdf` file. I thought the `\import` command modified the search paths for files in its command. My `graphicspath` is set so I can import graphics file from that directory tree just fine.

If I change the figure inclusion to:

```
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/teleoperation/solidworks_model_view.png}
```

Everything works perfectly fine. **Why can I not do the same with `\import` and `pdf_tex` files?**

For completeness, here is the `pdf_tex` file generated by Inkscape. THe offending `\includegraphics` directive is on line 52.

```
    %% Creator: Inkscape 0.91_64bit, www.inkscape.org
    %% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
    %% Accompanies image file 'solidworks_model_view.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
    %%
    %% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
    %%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
    %%  instead of
    %%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
    %% To scale the image, write
    %%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
    %%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
    %%  instead of
    %%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
    %%
    %% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
    %% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
    %% installed) using
    %%   \usepackage{import}
    %% in the preamble, and then including the image with
    %%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
    %% Alternatively, one can specify
    %%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
    %% 
    %% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
    %%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
    %%
    \begingroup%
      \makeatletter%
      \providecommand\color[2][]{%
        \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
        \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
      }%
      \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
        \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
        \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
      }%
      \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
      \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{1680bp}%
        \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
          \relax%
        \else%
          \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
        \fi%
      \else%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
      \fi%
      \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
      \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
      \makeatother%
      \begin{picture}(1,0.60119048)%
        \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{solidworks_model_view.pdf}}%
        \put(0.80420207,0.1664867){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$z$}}}%
        \put(0.77685686,0.12356509){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$x$}}}%
        \put(0.7926602,0.10007423){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$y$}}}%
      \end{picture}%
    \endgroup%
```

Comment: just use standard `\input{solidworks_model_view.pdf_tex}` and make sure that the directory with your tex/image combination is in your TEXINPUTS path

Comment: you can't use page key with `\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{solidworks_model_view.pdf}` use `\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{solidworks_model_view.pdf}`

Comment: @touhami `page` should work with pdf files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i did not know

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks fort he tip but I would prefer to not to alter environment variables, as I want to keep all my compilation steps portable between different computers (my University computer uses Windows and my home computer uses Linux).

Comment: you can set it in a texmf.cnf file in the current directory, doesn't have to be a system environment variable. or alternatively since its only the graphics file you need to find use `\graphicspath{{images/teleoperation/}}` in the preamble and that will effectively be prepended to the filename, you still just need `\input` for the tex file.

Comment: I have `\graphicspath{{../../phd_thesis_figs/}}` in the preamble. Could the relative path be upsetting to `\input`? `includegraphics` works perfectly fine for graphics and PDF diagrams when included in the TeX files directly. Changing the graphics path definition to `\graphicspath{{../../phd_thesis_figs/}{./}}` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've just been battling the same problem.

My solution was to add a `\graphicspath{{figs/}}` in the beginning of the file, so that it know where to look for the .pdf file. I'm not sure why, but adding `figs/` in the beginning of the input command `\input{figs/AMB-SyRM4d.pdf_tex}` was not enough.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Here is what worked for me. I first saved the Texmaker file into some folder, say figures. Then I generated Inkscape pdf_tex file and saved it in the same figures folder. Then I simply run `\input{filename.pdf_tex}` in the tex file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still wondering about this, I believe the reason why it didn't work in the original question is because the \import command was used incorrectly.
you should include the package import at the beginning of the document

```
\includepackage{import}
```

and then import command is used like this

```
\import{path/to/file/}{thefile.pdf_tex}
```

for me this is working fine and I don't need to change the graphicspath at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this still helps someone.

`/graphicspath` did not work for me on Overleaf (and I did not want to use import with specific paths all the time, after all my folder structure might change throughout a project). But one workaround they mention is described [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/An_introduction_to_Kpathsea_and_how_TeX_engines_search_for_files).

In short, create an empty file (I did this on the same level as main.tex, but I don't know if this is required) without any extension, call it `latexmkrc` and add

```
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./graphics//:'.$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
```

with `graphics` being your most upper level folder of interest.

As mentioned, I use Overleaf, but something similar should work on other platforms or at home too.